# Async server does not process requests while a request is stuck

Tags: grpc

I am new to GRPC so please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.  I am looking at the greeter_async_server.cc example code.  This seems to work fine for normal requests but I wanted to simulate a request getting stuck on the server so I added a sleep in the processing loop.  I added this right before Finish is called on the responder so that it was in the actual processing logic of the request.  While the server thread is sleeping it will not accept any new requests until the thread is free.  I attempted to create another client request while the original request on the server is sleeping but the grpc server would not process the request.  The client seemed to be stuck until the server came out of the sleep.

I also broke this process into debugger as well but the only request I saw was the one that was sleeping.  The other threads were waiting on the completion queue.

I am new to grpc so if I am doing this wrong please let me know what I need to do to handle request while another request is stuck.

```
void Proceed() {
      if (status_ == CREATE) {
        // Make this instance progress to the PROCESS state.
        status_ = PROCESS;

        // As part of the initial CREATE state, we *request* that the system
        // start processing SayHello requests. In this request, "this" acts are
        // the tag uniquely identifying the request (so that different CallData
        // instances can serve different requests concurrently), in this case
        // the memory address of this CallData instance.
        service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                  this);
      } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
        // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients while we process
        // the one for this CallData. The instance will deallocate itself as
        // part of its FINISH state.
        new CallData(service_, cq_);

        // The actual processing.
        std::string prefix("Hello ");
        reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

        Sleep((DWORD)-1);

        // And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
        // memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
        // the event.
        status_ = FINISH;
        responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
      } else {
        GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
        // Once in the FINISH state, deallocate ourselves (CallData).
        delete this;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just took the greeter_async_server.cc and added a sleep

Comment: Never mind.  I see the issue that we are processing the request which is blocked on the same thread that is monitoring the queue so in this case we just deadlocked ourselves.  This example should be updated to make this clear.